# Auto export talend project

Tags: talend

I want to export my Talend project daily in my local machine. I often forget to do this manually and it would be really helpful if there was a way of downloading it automatic. It's there a way you can auto export your Talend Open Studio project daily?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I tried to make a macro but doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a built-in Talend feature that can do this, but since a Talend project is just a directory with subfolders and files, you can setup a cron job that archives the project's main folder and copies it to another location.
An example with 7zip command:

**Windows**

```
7z.exe a -tzip /my/backup/folder/project.zip <TalendFolder>/workspace/PROJECT
```

**Linux**

```
7z a -tzip /my/backup/folder/project.zip <TalendFolder>/workspace/PROJECT
```

And schedule this in a .bat via Windows Scheduler (or a .sh with a cron job on linux)

Comment: thank you for answer. I'll try as quick as I can and let you know what happend.

Comment: I've included the exact syntax of the command, as well as the linux version, for future reference ;)

Answer (score 0):

The above code works fine, if you have to copy files on your harddrive. As soon, as there is a network drive involved as a target directory, the code takes very long to process the millions of small files, which are within the TOS workspace.

Therefore, I wrote the following script. (please excuse the german remarks within.)
It is based on 7z and robocopy.

7z should only add the new/changed files to the archiv and robocopy pushes the archive over to the target folder on a network share.

```
@echo off

echo.
echo --------------------------------
echo - start %date% %time% -
echo --------------------------------
echo.
echo.

REM choose working directory, where 7z should save the archive, before it is moved by robocopy
cd /D C:\Talend




REM define the name of your archive
set filename=TOS_DI_7.1_workspace_backup.7z

REM path of the directory, which should be put into the archive
set pathtobackup=C:\Talend\TOS_DI_7.1\workspace\

REM target path where the archive should be copied to
set destination=U:\Documents\TOS_DI_7.1\Backup\workspace


echo.
echo -------------------------------
echo - definition of the variables -
echo -------------------------------
echo.
echo This script creates an archive of the Talend Open Studio Workspace directory and copies it to the defined (network) directory.

echo current working direcotry:           %cd%
echo directory which is to be archived:   %pathtobackup%
echo name of the archive:                 %filename%
echo target directory:                    %destination%
echo directory for log files of robocopy: U:\Documents\TOS_DI_7.1\Backup\log\

REM please change log-directory below



echo.
echo.
echo --------------------------
echo - Start creating archive -
echo --------------------------
echo.
echo.

REM creation of archive
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" u -up0q0r2x2y2z1w2 -t7z %filename% %pathtobackup%

echo.
echo ---------------------------------
echo - creation of archive completed -
echo ---------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo -----------------
echo - Start copying -
echo -----------------
echo.
echo.    


REM robocopy copies the archive to the target directory
REM please change directory for log files here
robocopy %cd% %destination% %filename% /TEE/LOG+:"U:\Documents\TOS_DI_7.1\Backup\log\%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%_log.txt"


echo.
echo -------------------------------
echo - end %date% %time% -
echo -------------------------------
echo.
echo.


pause
```

Comment: This is not really helpful for someone who doesn't speak German. Can you remove or translate comments ?

Comment: I just translated the the comments. hope this helps